# Undirected tree, what about G'?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

**Please Note:** This is a part of bigger problem I finished proving one case and can't prove the following.

Let G be an undirected tree, such that G' isn't connected because it includes a node that isn't alone and not connected to all other nodes (There is some nodes that it can't reach). Find the contradiction.

**Note:** G' is the graph which includes all nodes in G and includes edges iff those edges do not exist in G.

Comment: Please state your problem clearly. The second paragraph is too messy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the vertices $u$ and $v$ are non-isolated vertices in different components of $G'$; then they are certainly not adjacent in $G'$, so they must be adjacent in $G$. If there is a vertex $w$ that is not adjacent to either of them in $G$, then $u-w-v$ is a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G'$, so there cannot be such a vertex: every vertex of $G$ other than $u$ and $v$ must be adjacent to $u$ or to $v$ (but not both — why?). In other words, $G$ must look something like this:

```
           *          *
            \        /
         *---u------v---*
            /|       \
           * *        *
```

- Show that if $v$ is the only neighbor of $u$ in $G$, then $v$ is isolated in $G'$, contrary to hypothesis. Similarly, $u$ cannot be the only neighbor of $v$ in $G$.
- Show that if $u$ has a neighbor $x\ne v$ and $v$ has a neighbor $y\ne u$, then there is a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G'$.

Comment: Where did you use the fact that one edge isn't alone? is it u or v? plus you supposed multiple things which are not true for sure

Comment: @Daniel98: You mean the fact that one **vertex** isn’t isolated? That comes into play in the first bullet point. Of course I supposed something that isn’t true: I supposed that there are non-isolated vertices in different components of $G$. I did it because this is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: I have already used contradiction so you can't use it again...

Comment: @Daniel98: Whether you have at some point used contradiction is irrelevant. Although I left a couple of details to you, I essentially answered your question completely: I pointed out exactly why the situation that you described is impossible (i.e., self-contradictory). Apparently you aren’t serious about wanting an answer.